# How to convert String to Equivalent Ascii(Hex) in Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I want to make a property in pom.xml and assign some string to it let say "A" now i want to convert A to ascii in hex as 0x41 and use it in my pom.xml.

Is there any way to do this in pom.xml?

Comment: Why would like to do such thing in a pom file? Can you show an example use case?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using it for javacard build, where AID of applet goes in hex only, i wanted to convert some text as AID for verification purpose.